# Why do most PCI Cards for USB 3.0 only have PCI Express 2.0 x1?

Tags: usb, pci-express

They claim to have 5 Gbps which is 625 MBps. But PCIe 2.0 x1 only has a bandwidth of 500 MBps. Am I overlooking something? Are there reasons the hardware developers are doing this? To my understanding it would be better to use at least PCIe 2.0 x2. So why are they not using x2?

Which PCIe 2.0 Card would you recommend for internal USB 3.0 to get full 5 Gbps on the front panel via USB 3.0 Type A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB 3.0, while running physically at 5 Gbps, can transfer only 500 MBytes/s, because each byte is 8b/10b encoded, and thus uses ten bits per each byte.

The 500 MB/s is not even theoretical throughput, because there is protocol overhead, link management overhead, and system overhead. The link and power management overhead is handled at PHY hardware level, which further reduces the actual system load. The best throughput, I believe, was reported by Cypress with their [FX3 controllers](https://www.cypress.com/file/125281/download), and was about 450 MB/s. Therefore the PCIe 2.0 1x is perfectly aligned for the USB 3.0 job.

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed overlooking something. It is not just about technical specs though, it is about marketing and cost.

Basically you have two choices:

1. A low cost design which is fast enough in most cases, sells well and still can claim the 5Gb/s signaling rate. (true, even if you cannot sustaint he matching thoughput).
2. Build a more expensive part for people who actually connect something very fast to it. Which is rather weird to do with USB anyway since you loose a lot on overhead. So those people are better served with eSATA, thunderbolt etc etc.

Comment: Why can they claim the 5 Gb/s?

Comment: Because the interface is 5GB/sec.  Same at SATA interface used to be 3Gb/sec even when a rating rust drive could deliver only a fraction of that.